# How to serve static files in route "/" together with other routes

Tags: r, plumber

I need to serve both static files and endpoints on the same Plumber API server. My idea is:

- route `/` will serve static HTML files (like `index.html`)
- route `/test` will execute a R command (like `list("TEST API")`

My folder contains as follows:

- a `init.R` file that starts the Plumber server
- a `api` folder that contains endpoints definitions
- a `api/assets` folder that contains the static file (in this case `index.html`)

**init.R**

```
library(plumber)

options(plumber.trailingSlash = TRUE)

pr <- Plumber$new()

pr <- pr %>%
  pr_mount("/", plumb("api/assets.R")) %>%
  pr_mount("/test", plumb("api/test.R"))

pr_run(pr, host = "0.0.0.0", port = 8080)
```

**api/assets.R**

```
#* Assets for front end
#* @assets api/assets /
list()
```

**api/test.R**

```
#* Test API
#* @get /
function() {
  list("TEST API")
}
```

Now, if I query the URL `http://localhost:8080` I got the content of the `index.html` file stored in `api/assets` folder:

```bash
# > curl http://localhost:8080
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello World!
</body>
```

Instead, if I query `locahost:8080/test` I got *Resource Not Found*:

```
# > curl http://localhost:8080/test
{"error":"404 - Resource Not Found"}
```

If I remove static mounting, `/test` works correctly. Is there a way to mounting both static files in `/` **and** endpoints in sub-routes?

Thank you,
Domi